# Como gerar um json com um array de objetos

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa, h2database

Olá, eu estou tentando criar uma API REST, onde no método GET devo retornar um JSON nesse estilo:

```
{questions:[{
  id: 1,
  question: 'pergunta 1',
  answers: [{
    answerText: 'resposta 1',
    correctAnswer: true
  },
  {
    answerText: 'resposta 2',
    correctAnswer: false
  }
 ]
}
```

estou utilizando JPA e meu código para gerar um json simples utiliza apenas a classe da seguinte maneira:

```
package com.example.quizgame;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return this.answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

}
```

gostaria de saber como converter uma classe simples para uma que consiga inserir um array de objetos no array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro do seu question você pode colocar uma coleção

```
@OneToMany
List<Answer> answers;
```

Pesquise mais sobre essa anotação para evitar alguns problemas que podem acontecer, mas basicamente é isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu tava querendo muito uma luz, tava muito perdido por ser a minha primeira vez usando spring, vou ir atrás sim, mais uma pergunta se não for incômodo é possível gerar esse JSON onde os itens estão ordenados aleatoriamente?

Comment: @LuisGustavoRodriguesOliveir acho que não entendi bem a sua pergunta. No seu exemplo eles estão em ordem por id. Você quer aleatória?

Comment: não é que eu queria sempre pegar os dados de forma aleatória do back end, mas eu ja consegui resolver muito obrigado por tudo